# JSONP xss scenario

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp, xss

I just receive a security report pointing XSS vulnerability to one JSONP call which could be exploited on the JSONP id,

```
http://<domain>/?callback=jQuery278364782634836_234}}7d1ef<script>alert(1)<%2fscript>13c10&_=14531234
```

From my understanding this is impossible to happen since the id is generated by jQuery. Can someone give example how this can be injected maliciously in production scenario ?

Comment: If your server automatically generates the name of the callback function based on what it's passed in the `callback` part of the GET request without any clean up, it is indeed an XSS vector, all though only to the page requesting the JSONP file at that time.

Comment: @adeneo ... and since the id is generated by jQuery it is impossible for it to be used maliciously, right ?

Comment: As long as the functions name is generated with jQuery, yes, but that same JSONP script could be requested by anyone, from anywhere

Comment: In your question is `<domain>` your domain or a 3rd party? Also, which ID is generated by JQuery?